# How to do text in pill container and arraged dynamically like this photo in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, measure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNg2S.png)

Dynamically arrange text pill container.
Size of widgets is not return rowList.add(MeasureSize()) in this stage.I only return size of widget when return widget of Consumer Builder. What should I do to return size of the widget?
Example:
double size = getSizeOfThisWidget(Container(child:Text('Hello Flutter pill text'));
Can I get size of widget when I call like this function or method?

```
Consumer<CategoryProvider>(
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
    List<dynamic> data = value.categoryData;
    int length = data.length;
    List<Widget> mainList = [];
    List<Widget> rowList = [];
    double limit = size.width - 40;
    double width = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      FolderModel folderModel = FolderModel(
        id: data[index]['id'],
        folderName: data[index]['folderName'],
        categoryLevel: data[index]['categoryLevel'],
      );
      rowList.add(MeasureSize(
        onChange: (size) {
          width += size.width;
          print(size);
        },
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 14, vertical: 6),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            color: KColors.kPillBgColor,
          ),
          child: Text(
            folderModel.folderName,
            style: KTextStyle.kNormalTextStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ));

      if (width > limit) {
        rowList.removeLast();
        mainList.add(Row(
          children: rowList,
        ));
        rowList = [];
        width = 0;
      }
    }
    return Column(
      children: mainList,
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Please actually enter an image description when prompted to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a family of widgets called `Chips`. You can read more about it here https://m2.material.io/components/chips#types

Simply put, there are 5 chips each with their own functionality

1. Chip
2. InputChip
3. ChoiceChip
4. FilterChip
5. ActionChip

See the flutter documentation for chips here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html

The chip that you are looking for is the [FilterChip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html) and you can implement it in your code as:

```
  FilterChip(
    label: Text(
      folderModel.folderName,
      style: KTextStyle.kNormalTextStyle,
    ),
    selected: folderModel.isSelected,
    onSelected: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
        folderModel.isSelected = value;
      });
    },
  )
```

Ensure to keep track of the selected state. I don't know how you have structured your code so I am assuming you have a parameter called `isSelected` in your `FolderModel` to determine and change its selected state.

Comment: Three FliterChip can add in one row. May be two. May be one. I wanna arrange like this. FliterChip is user input.

Comment: You can rather let Flutter decide a neat way to arrange them by wrapping all the chips in a `Wrap` widget which will fill the row until there's no more space and then it will add another row. Have a look at this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: I got it now. I use Wrap widget and filter chip. Thank sir.